# Create boot image from python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, iso

I want to create a bootable .iso image so that I can boot from a python file. Can you suggest how to do it?

I haven't tried anything and expect to be able to boot from .py files

Comment: To my knowledge you can't "boot from a Python file". What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that I can make a bootable .iso image with a python file and then boot from it.

Comment: You can create a Linux bootable ISO which automatically starts a Python file. I think this is more a question for https://superuser.com

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker, It does something like this.
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/).